# Finer grained audio and Bluetooth control?

Tags: bluetooth-audio, oxygenos

I'm running OnePlus 6 with current oxygenOS (10.3.7) based on Android 10.

When listening to music on a Bluetooth device it's really annoying to hear notification sounds, is there any way to get finer control which audio goes to BT and which plays locally?
It's a shame notifications on apps like WhatsApp seem to be controlled through Media not Ring.

Comment: According some posts I found some manufacturer seem to include a separate "notifications" volume setting (e.g. Samsung, LG and may be others seem to have or had such a setting on certain devices).

Comment: Not the case for me on Pixel 4a, Android 11